# Read url of online-link(.url) with batch

Tags: batch-file, url, steam

So far I have this code(using Craft The World as example):

```
type "Craft The World.url"|find "URL"
```

And if I run it in cmd it outputs this:

```
URL=steam://rungameid/248390
```

How can I save this into a variable? I tried `SET A=...` but it didn't work...

My goal is to then extract the ID(last 6 characters) from this, but I can substring in bat once I have the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use the `type` command; use [input redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) (`<`) to read the file and pass it into the `find` command.

To capture the last line of the standard output of a command line and store it into a variable (`LINE`), use a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html):

```cmd
for /F "tokens=1* delims== eol=" %%I in ('^< "Craft The World.url" find "URL"') do set "LINE=%%J"
echo Last line: "%LINE%"
```

To process multiple lines of output, do that within the body of the loop, using the `for` variable reference `%%J` directly:

```cmd
for /F "tokens=1* delims== eol==" %%I in ('^< "Craft The World.url" find "URL"') do (
    echo Line string: "%%J"
)
```

The above approaches both split off the `URL=` prefix by making use of the `tokens` and `delims` options of the `for /F` command.

---

With your string `URL=steam://rungameid/248390`, you can kind of misuse the [`~` modifies](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) of the `for` variable reference `%%J`:

```cmd
for /F "tokens=1* delims== eol=" %%I in ('^< "Craft The World.url" find "URL"') do (
    echo Line string : "%%J"
    echo Last element: "%%~nxJ"
)
```

This works, because the `/` becomes converted to the standard path separator `\`, so `steam://rungameid/248390` becomes `steam:\\rungameid\248390` internally, whereof the last path element is extracted by the `~n` and `~x` modifiers. The other path modifiers do not return anything useful, because they work reliable only when no `/` but only `\` occur.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop to get what you want:

```
for /f %%i in ('type "Craft The World.url"^|find "URL"') do (
    set "A=%%i"
)
```

Take into account that if the output contains several lines you wouldn't get in `A` what you expect.